# Failed to save undefined: The attribute "displayDatePicker" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://ui:inputText: Source

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
   <ui:inputText aura:id="grcpno"
                 label="gr cpno"
                 class="slds-input"
                 labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                 value="{!v.grcpno.Name}"
                 required="true"/>

</div>

</div>


<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
   <ui:inputText aura:id="startDate"
                 label="Start Date"
                 class="slds-input"
                 labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                 value="{!v.StartDate.Date__c}"
                displayDatePicker="true"/>

</div>

</div>

<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
   <ui:inputText aura:id="endDate"
                 label="End Date"
                 class="slds-input"
                 labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                 value="{!v.endDate.Date__c}"
                 displayDatePicker="true"/>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use ui:inputDate not ui:inputText

[image]

Comment: Can you share me the url of the above information. I would like to see the syntax

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm